# eric meyer's css reset affecting headings

Tags: html, css

I am using Eric Meyer's css reset 2. But when using a heading in my website, the headings are all same size and small text. I have seen that the problem comes from css reset. I tried remove the headings from there, but now they seem to have a padding from top. Here is a fiddle example: jsfiddle.net/50c9dsyu/.

```css
h1 {
  color: gray; }
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link href="sass\main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css\reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>I like pizza</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put your main.css reference below reset.css

Comment: Still not working

Comment: That is what a reset is supposed to do! You are probably aiming at normalization check `normalize.css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is the expected behavior of any CSS reset. Any CSS you add needs to be below the reset rules. I have updated your fiddle.

```
/* Reset code goes here */

.myRule { 
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/50c9dsyu/2/

Note the rule for the H1 is now at the bottom of the CSS.